# Adding decimal number to MS Access query

Tags: ms-access, decimal

I have a Completed field in Access that is a number data type. The number in this field is 1 for all records unless the record has a status of "Cancelled". In this case the number is to 0.5.

However, when I input the 0.5 value, Access rounds the number to 0. I tried updating the format to
Format([Table].[Field Name]),"Fixed"), but the values of 0 and 1 continue to show, not 0.5.

How can I get the 0.5 to show in the field?

Comment: What is the type of the underlying field ?

Comment: The type is number

Comment: What number size - Integer, Double, Long Integer? Make sure it is Double. Or use a Yes/No field. Or even more informative would be date/time CompletionDate. Why 0.5 for False?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the 0.5 to show in the field?

Change the data type of the field from *Integer* or *Long* to *Double*.